# how to compare ids and variable in if else loop and execute it in jquery ui

Tags: html, jquery-ui

html5 code:

```
<h1 id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" > Header1 </h1>
<p id="drag1" class="ui-widget-content"> Paragraph </p> 
<p id="drag2" class="ui-widget-content"> text box </p>
<p id="drag3" class="ui-widget-content" > radio button </p>

<div id="droppable"></div>
```

jquery code:

```
$(function() {
$(".ui-widget-content").click(function() {
  var clickedId= $(this).attr("id");
  alert(clickedId);
});

$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ appendTo: "body", helper: "clone"});
$( "#drag1" ).draggable({ appendTo: "body", helper: "clone"});
$( "#drag2" ).draggable({ appendTo: "body", helper: "clone"});
$( "#drag3" ).draggable({ appendTo: "body", helper: "clone"});


$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
drop: function( event, ui ) {

if(clickedId == draggable){
 $( "<textarea></textarea>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
 $("textarea").draggable();
}
else if(clickedId==drag1){
  $( "<textarea></textarea>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
  $("textarea").draggable();
}
else if(clickedId==drag2){
 $( "<input></input>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
 $("input").draggable();
}
else if(clickedId==drag3){
 $( "<button></button>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
 $("buton").draggable();
}
}
});
});
```

once the html element is dragged and dropped in the drop area it should execute the appropriate if else loop. The problem is that after drag and drop it is not executing the if else loop by comparing the id stored in the clickedId.

Comment: Indentation is a *good thing*.

Comment: First time I posted hence the mistake. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issue in your code,

1. One as suggested by
   [@jnmrobinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2435083/jnmrobinson)

   `if(clickedId == 'draggable'){`
2. You need to set`clickedId` as Global variable so use ,

   `$(".ui-widget-content").click(function() {`
     `clickedId= $(this).attr("id");});`

#### And , here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2c4b0pha/1/).

**Suggestion** :

I don't know if it stated to use click before doing `drag` event in your requirement but you can get ***drag element id*** in `drop` event of droppable,

```
drop: function( event, ui ) {
    var dragId = ui.draggable.prop("id");
```

Comment: The suggestion that you gave was the exact thing that I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

When testing for clickedId you should be getting strings, so wrap quotes around the values:

```
if(clickedId == 'draggable'){
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it did not work. It is not changing the dropped element to text area or button as in the code